# How to implement fast series multiplication

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, functional-style

I need to generalize the `SeriesData` object for my own purposes.  One of the things I need to do is to reimplement code to multiply product of series.

I've made two attempts at this, and both of them are slower than the built-in `SeriesData`.  Is there an algorithm that has better `Timing` than mine?

```
(*Two of my implementations*)
multSerList1[lists__] := 
    Array[Plus @@ Times @@@ (MapThread[Part, {{lists}, #}, 1] & /@ 
      Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[#, {3}], 1]) &, Min[Length /@ {lists}], Length[{lists}]];

multSerList2[listFirst_, listRest__] := 
    Fold[Function[{a1, a2}, Array[Inner[Times, Take[a1, #], Reverse[Take[a2, #]], Plus] &, Min[Length /@ 
      {listFirst, listRest}]]], listFirst, {listRest}];
```

To test this, I try to multiply the following three series together:

```
realExampleList = {
  List @@ Normal[Series[Exp[y x], {x, 0, 4}]], 
  List @@ Normal[Series[Log[1 + c x], {x, 0, 5}]],
  List @@ Normal[Series[PolyLog[2, -n x], {x, 0, 3}]]}
```

Then `multSerList1@@realExampleList` or `multSerList2@@ realExampleList` both yield

> [image]

I can apply `AbsoluteTiming` to time my code.  It takes 0.0002 s for first one and 0.0001 s for the second one on my machine.  But Multiplying the `SeriesData` (need to remove the `Normal` and `List`)

```
realExampleListSerData = {
  Series[Exp[y x], {x, 0, 4}], 
  Series[Log[1 + c x], {x, 0, 5}],
  Series[PolyLog[2, -n x], {x, 0, 3}]};
```

By simply doing `Times@@realExampleListSerData`, it gets the answer in 0.00002 s, which is five times faster.

I need help implementing the multiplication of series that performs approximately as well as the `SeriesData`.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not simply writing a wrapper for the built-in `SeriesData` object? That way, you can simply use the multiplication implemented for `SeriesData` when implementing the multiplication of your wrapper, with negligible overhead

Comment: If the series coefficient lists are long, you might get better performance using `ListConvolve`.

Comment: @LukasLang I need to make slight modifications to it, so I cannot simply use `SeriesData`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Interesting, though I'm not seeing how to use `ListConvolve`.  Can you provide a short example of how I can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea for using convolution. I suspect there is similar in the reference page for `ListConvolve`. I first illustrate in a slightly roundabout way, by creating explicit polynomials and then extracting coefficient lists.

```
SeedRandom[1234]
s = 10;
n = 8;
p1 = randomPoly[n, s, x]
p2 = randomPoly[n, s, x]
c1 = CoefficientList[p1, x]
c2 = CoefficientList[p2, x]

(* Out[1843]= -9 + 10 x + 10 x^2 - 9 x^3 - 10 x^4 + 6 x^5 + 7 x^6 - 
 6 x^7 + x^8

Out[1844]= -5 + 9 x + 5 x^2 + 6 x^3 + 9 x^4 - 8 x^5 + 2 x^6 - 
 5 x^7 + x^8

Out[1845]= {-9, 10, 10, -9, -10, 6, 7, -6, 1}

Out[1846]= {-5, 9, 5, 6, 9, -8, 2, -5, 1} *)
```

Now compare expanding and convolution, with the latter having argument settings to achieve Cauchy product convolution.

```
Expand[p1*p2]
ListConvolve[c1, c2, {1, -1}, 0]

(* Out[1847]= 45 - 131 x - 5 x^2 + 131 x^3 - 2 x^4 + 57 x^5 - 93 x^6 - 
 33 x^7 - 45 x^8 + 97 x^9 + 19 x^10 - 51 x^11 + 31 x^12 - 49 x^13 + 
 39 x^14 - 11 x^15 + x^16

Out[1848]= {45, -131, -5, 131, -2, 57, -93, -33, -45, 97, 19, -51, \
31, -49, 39, -11, 1} *)
```

Here is a larger example. For `Series` I have to double the order so as to get all coefficients in the product. You would not actually do that for series products, I'm doing it to show that the results match.

```
SeedRandom[1234]
bign = 10^4;
bigp1 = randomPoly[bign, s, x];
bigp2 = randomPoly[bign, s, x];
bigs1 = Series[bigp1, {x, 0, 2*bign}];
bigs2 = Series[bigp2, {x, 0, 2*bign}];
bigc1 = CoefficientList[bigp1, x];
bigc2 = CoefficientList[bigp2, x];
Timing[bigsprod = bigs1*bigs2;]
Timing[bigpprod = Expand[bigp1*bigp2];]
Timing[biglc = ListConvolve[bigc1, bigc2, {1, -1}, 0];]
biglc === bigsprod[[3]] === CoefficientList[bigpprod, x]

(* Out[1910]= {42.8077, Null}

Out[1911]= {0.02545, Null}

Out[1912]= {0.000905, Null}

Out[1913]= True *)
```

One can improve a bit on the convolution timing by setting the second parameter so that higher order terms are omitted.

Comment: So it seems `ListConvolve[c1, c2, {1, -1}, 0]` is exactly what I am looking for!  Thank you.  I still have to better acquaint myself with `ListConvolute` and friends.  I can raise the second element of the list to truncate the desired number of terms. Maybe something like `ListConvolve[c1, c2, {1, -Length[c1]}, 0]`  Do I understand that correctly?  Thanks again!

Comment: I think so. I've not checked parameter settings specific to series-style multiplication but what you write looks like it might be correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed maximum degree of polynomials, you can compute the product of two generic polynomials. This is in some sense similar to a naive implementation of symbolic automatic differentiation.

```
ClearAll[make$mult] ;
make$mult[] := Block[
    {x, a, b, c1, c2, p1, p2, p3, arg, list},
    p1 = a0 + Dot[c1 = ToExpression[Map[StringTemplate["a``"],Range[order]]],x^Range[order]] ;
    p2 = b0 + Dot[c2 = ToExpression[Map[StringTemplate["b``"],Range[order]]],x^Range[order]] ;
    p3 = Collect[p1*p2,x] /. x^w_ /; w > order -> 0 ;
    arg = {a0,c1,b0,c2} // Flatten ;
    list = CoefficientList[p3,x] ;
    Apply[Function,{arg,list}]
] ;

ClearAll[make$jet] ;
make$jet[expression_] := Apply[jet,CoefficientList[Normal[Series[expression,{x,0,order}]] + w*x^order,x] /. w -> 0]

ClearAll[make$poly] ;
make$poly[jet[list__]] := {list}.x^Range[0,Length[{list}]-1] ;

ClearAll[jet] ;
jet /: Times[jet[a__],jet[b__]] := Apply[jet,Apply[mult,{a,b}]] ;

(* example *)
(* set max order *)
order = 4 ;
(* generate mult (one time computation, can be compiled) *)
ClearAll[mult] ;
mult = make$mult[] ;
(* polynomials *)
p1 = Exp[y x] ;
p2 = Log[1 + c x] ;
p3 = PolyLog[2, -n x] ;
(* convert to jets *)
j1 = make$jet[p1] ;
j2 = make$jet[p2] ;
j3 = make$jet[p3] ;
(* mult and convert to polynomial *)
res = make$poly[j1*j2*j3] ; // RepeatedTiming
(* compare *)
realExampleListSerData = {
  Series[Exp[y x], {x, 0, 4}], 
  Series[Log[1 + c x], {x, 0, 5}],
  Series[PolyLog[2, -n x], {x, 0, 3}]};
ref = Normal[Times@@realExampleListSerData] ; // RepeatedTiming
res - ref // Expand
(* {0.0000534, Null} *)
(* {0.0000131, Null} *)
(* 0 *)
```